# time.now return value (and some other questions)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a few more basic questions about Ruby on Rails.

1) When I call time.now, I get this result: `2011-06-21 19:11:00.518140`
The time/date-notation is fine for me, but what is that .518140? Is there an easy way to remove this?

2) It seems my server time is also incorrect (it's not 19:11 right now). I'm using WEBrick; where can I change the time?

3) I'm using a basic authentication system with this code (from the RoR tutorials):

```
  def authenticate
    authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |user_name, password|
      user_name == 'admin' && password = 'admin'
    end
  end
```

It works fine, but when I enter an incorrect password, I get a white page with the text `HTTP Basic: Access denied.` Is there a way to change this error page to something more user-friendly?

Thank you!

Comment: You should probably make those three different questions, to increase the chance of people answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** That would be microseconds. Try `Time.now.to_s(:db)`
`:db` is defined as `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` which you can use without Rails ActiveSupport like this

```
Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

**2.** That depends on what OS you are running.

Comment: Thank you very much, that also seems to solve the incorrect time for some reason :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason the time is different is that you probably aren't running on UTC time (which is the default).